# How to Convert OR condition in Postgres to seqeuelize query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following query in my postgres query,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone ='081234568912' OR email = 'idafdsafsdfads@gmail.com';
```

Now I want to find the data using sequelize

This is my code, `this.app('books').find({query:{phone:data.phone, email:data.email}, paginate:false})`

It only executes AND command not OR

Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you are querying with findAll/find or doing bulk updates/destroys you can pass a where object to filter the query.

where generally takes an object from attribute:value pairs, where value can be primitives for equality matches or keyed objects for other operators.

It's also possible to generate complex AND/OR conditions by nesting sets of or and and Operators.

Seems there is another format now. putting just comma will be considered as AND operation you can use OR as an operator as below

```
where: {
    LastName: "Doe",
    $or: [
        {
            FirstName: 
            {
                $eq: "John"
            }
        }, 
        {
            FirstName: 
            {
                $eq: "Jane"
            }
        }, 
        {
            Age: 
            {
                $gt: 18
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Will generate

```
WHERE LastName='Doe' AND (FirstName = 'John' OR FirstName = 'Jane' OR Age > 18)
```

Refer to the documentation : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where